# Как получить строку в js, с тега?

Tags: javascript, html

```html
 <div class="first">Сегодня такая отличная погода  0411</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let text = document.querySelector('.first').textContent;
```

Comment: спасибо) только с точкой класс

Comment: Да, я его сразу поправил